# Persistent large file error on `git push` even after large file is removed

Tags: github

I accidently tried to push a large file to git and I got the following error message:

```
=Counting objects: 1565, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1559/1559), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1565/1565), 142.13 MiB | 3.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 1565 (delta 1212), reused 2 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1212/1212), completed with 11 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: e3e1d72efbc7d183eda3ef58d3ef93ad
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File pycotools/Examples/Fit1Dir/smad7_not_reproduced_alternative/file.csv is 1607.96 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/PyCoTools.git
 ! [remote rejected] CopasiVersion19 -> CopasiVersion19 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/PyCoTools.git'
```

I have since remove this file from both of my branches but I still keep getting the same error and therefore can't `push` any of my code. Does anybody have any ideas on what to do here?

**update**

Following a [suggestion](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/) in comments

```
$ git rm --cached /Examples/Fit1Dir/smad7_not_reproduced_alternative/file.csv
```

produces:

```
fatal: pathspec 'pycotools/Examples/Fit1Dir/smad7_not_reproduced_alternative/file.csv' did not match any files
```

Comment: [Removing files from a repository's history](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried step 1 of your suggestion and it appears git cannot find the file.

Comment: then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository